# SQL Server 2008 View Automatically Renaming Aliases to Expr1, Expr2, etc

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, view

My aliases keep getting renamed to Expr1, Expr2, etc. after saving my view. I have multiple CASE WHEN THEN statements in the view that have the same aliases in each case statement (X0,Y0 and Z0.) Essentially all case statements after the first case statement replaces my aliases with this Expr1, Expr2.
Any help would be extremely appreciated. I also tried putting square brackets around the aliases but that did not work.

I should also note that when I go to save, I get a warning from SQL Server Management Studio about my order by clause. It's probably unrelated but you never know.

```
SELECT
TOP (100) PERCENT
  s.dtmEvaluation AS SurgeryDate,
  p.idPatient,
  d.strLead AS LeadType,
  ds.strDBSSite AS Target,
  CASE
    WHEN intSide = 0 THEN 'L'
    ELSE 'R'
  END AS Side,
  ROUND(s.dblACX, 2, 1) AS ACX,
  ROUND(s.dblACZ, 2, 1) AS ACY,
  ROUND(s.dblACZ, 2, 1) AS ACZ,
  ROUND(s.dblPCX, 2, 1) AS PCX,
  ROUND(s.dblPCY, 2, 1) AS PCY,
  ROUND(s.dblPCZ, 2, 1) AS PCZ,
  ROUND(s.dblInitX, 2, 1) AS InitialX,
  ROUND(s.dblInitY, 2, 1) AS [Initial Y],
  ROUND(s.dblInitZ, 2, 1) AS [Initial Z],
  s.dblACPCAngle AS InitialACPCAngle,
  s.dblCenterAngle AS InitialCLangle,
  s.dblMicroPasses AS MicroPasses,
  s.dblMacroPasses AS MacroPasses,
  ROUND(s.dblFinalX, 2, 1) AS FinalX,
  ROUND(s.dblFinalY, 2, 1) AS FinalY,
  ROUND(s.dblFinalZ, 2, 1) AS FinalZ,
  ROUND(s.dblMeasuredX, 2, 1) AS MeasX,
  ROUND(s.dblMeasuredY, 2, 1) AS MeasY,
  ROUND(s.dblMeasuredZ, 2, 1) AS MeasZ,
  s.dblMeasuredACPCAngle,
  s.dblMeasuredCtrAngle,
  ROUND(SQRT(POWER(s.dblMeasuredX - s.dblFinalX, 2) + POWER(s.dblMeasuredY - s.dblFinalY, 2) + POWER(s.dblMeasuredZ - s.dblFinalZ,2)), 2, 1) AS Delta,
  CASE
    WHEN s.intSide = 1 THEN s.dblMeasuredx + ((dblelectrodelength - 1) + 0 * (dblelectrodespacing + dblelectrodelength) + (dblelectrodelength / 2)) *         SIN(RADIANS(dblMeasuredCtrAngle))
    ELSE dblMeasuredx - ((dblelectrodelength - 1) + 0 * (dblelectrodespacing + dblelectrodelength) + (dblelectrodelength / 2)) * SIN(RADIANS(dblMeasuredCtrAngle))
  END AS X0,
  s.dblMeasuredY +
  (((d.dblElectrodeLength - 1)
  + 0 * (d.dblElectrodeSpacing + d.dblElectrodeLength)) +
  d.dblElectrodeLength / 2) * COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredACPCAngle))
  * COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredCtrAngle)) AS Y0,
  s.dblMeasuredZ + (((d.dblElectrodeLength - 1) + 0 *
  (d.dblElectrodeSpacing + d.dblElectrodeLength))
  + d.dblElectrodeLength / 2) *
  SIN(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredACPCAngle)) *
  COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredCtrAngle)) AS Z0,
  CASE
    WHEN intSide = 1 THEN dblMeasuredx +
      ((dblelectrodelength - 1) + 1 * (dblelectrodespacing +
      dblelectrodelength) + (dblelectrodelength / 2))
      * SIN(RADIANS(dblMeasuredCtrAngle))
    ELSE dblMeasuredx -
      ((dblelectrodelength - 1) + 1 * (dblelectrodespacing +
      dblelectrodelength) + (dblelectrodelength / 2))
      * SIN(RADIANS(dblMeasuredCtrAngle))
  END AS Expr1,
  s.dblMeasuredY + (((d.dblElectrodeLength - 1) + 1 *
  (d.dblElectrodeSpacing + d.dblElectrodeLength))
  + d.dblElectrodeLength / 2) *
  COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredACPCAngle)) *
  COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredCtrAngle)) AS Expr2,
  s.dblMeasuredZ + (((d.dblElectrodeLength - 1) + 1 *
  (d.dblElectrodeSpacing + d.dblElectrodeLength)) + d.dblElectrodeLength /
  2)
  * SIN(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredACPCAngle)) *
  COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredCtrAngle)) AS Expr3,
  CASE
    WHEN intSide = 1 THEN dblMeasuredx + ((dblelectrodelength - 1)
      + 2 * (dblelectrodespacing + dblelectrodelength) +
      (dblelectrodelength / 2)) * SIN(RADIANS(dblMeasuredCtrAngle))
    ELSE dblMeasuredx - ((dblelectrodelength - 1)
      + 2 * (dblelectrodespacing + dblelectrodelength) +
      (dblelectrodelength / 2)) * SIN(RADIANS(dblMeasuredCtrAngle))
  END AS
  Expr4,
  s.dblMeasuredY + (((d.dblElectrodeLength - 1) + 2 *
  (d.dblElectrodeSpacing + d.dblElectrodeLength)) + d.dblElectrodeLength
  / 2)
  * COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredACPCAngle)) *
  COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredCtrAngle)) AS Expr5,
  s.dblMeasuredZ +
  (((d.dblElectrodeLength - 1)
  + 2 * (d.dblElectrodeSpacing + d.dblElectrodeLength)) +
  d.dblElectrodeLength / 2) * SIN(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredACPCAngle)) *
  COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredCtrAngle))
  AS Expr6,
  CASE
    WHEN intSide = 1 THEN dblMeasuredx +
      ((dblelectrodelength - 1) + 3 * (dblelectrodespacing +
      dblelectrodelength) + (dblelectrodelength / 2))
      * SIN(RADIANS(dblMeasuredCtrAngle))
    ELSE dblMeasuredx -
      ((dblelectrodelength - 1) + 3 * (dblelectrodespacing +
      dblelectrodelength) + (dblelectrodelength / 2))
      * SIN(RADIANS(dblMeasuredCtrAngle))
  END AS Expr7,
  s.dblMeasuredY + (((d.dblElectrodeLength - 1) + 3 *
  (d.dblElectrodeSpacing + d.dblElectrodeLength))
  + d.dblElectrodeLength / 2) *
  COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredACPCAngle)) *
  COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredCtrAngle)) AS Expr8,
  s.dblMeasuredZ + (((d.dblElectrodeLength - 1) + 3 *
  (d.dblElectrodeSpacing + d.dblElectrodeLength)) + d.dblElectrodeLength /
  2)
  * SIN(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredACPCAngle)) *
  COS(RADIANS(s.dblMeasuredCtrAngle)) AS Expr9,
  s.dblAtlasScaleX,
  s.dblAtlasScaleY,
  s.dblAtlasScaleZ,
  s.dblAtlasMovementX,
  s.dblAtlasMovementY,
  s.dblAtlasMovementZ,
  s.dblAtlasRotationX,
  s.dblAtlasRotationY,
  s.dblAtlasRotationZ
FROM dbo.tblDBSSurgery AS s
INNER JOIN dbo.tblPatientDemographics AS p
  ON p.idPatient =
  s.idPatient
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblLookupLeads AS d
  ON d.idLead = s.intLeadType
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblLookupDBSSites AS ds
  ON ds.idDBSSite = s.intSite
WHERE (s.intProcedure = 0
OR s.intProcedure = 2)
AND (s.blnOutside = 0)
AND (NOT
(p.strMRN = '09999999'))
AND (NOT (p.strMRN = '08888888'))
ORDER BY surgerydate
```

Comment: Are you using * in your `select` clause?

Comment: Hi Andrea, no I'm not.

Comment: Can you please edit your question adding the TSQL code for your view?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing the source code...

Comment: Does this help you guys?

Comment: That formatting was awful, I simply used http://www.sql-format.com/ to make it somewhat legible. Which column aliases aren't returning what you have them aliased as in the code above? I see multiple Expr# aliases. i'd expect them to be returned.

Comment: The first alias of each case statement after the first case statement should return X0, the second alias within the case statement should return Y0, the third should return Z0. Instead they return Expr1..and so forth.

Comment: Are you editing it in design mode? If so, right click the view in object explorer, then select "Script view as - Alter To - New query window". Make your changes in there, and execute that. The design view is trying to work with all three panes, and it can get confused and mess things up.